# Opening an activity with a webview (and url) restarts application

Tags: android, webview, android-cursorloader

I am working on a small app that uses cursorloaders and loader callbacks. I am new to loader callbacks. The app displays a list of items and on item click a new activity is called that loads a url in a webview. I am not finishing the parent activity, but it so happens that when the webpage loads completely after some 1 or 2 minutes the previous activity restarts.

I did not know what to put in as the question since i am not sure if it the webpage that causes the restart of it the loader that causes the activity to restart. Though i have read the documentation and also:

[this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html), but none of them talks about a restart.

I have also looked at [this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146626/webview-restarts-application-if-jquery-mobile-implemented-webpage-is-opened-in-webview) , but got no clue. Could this be a cause for the application restart ?

I am calling the following link in the webview activity:
[url](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/royals/id703590196?i=703590283&ign-mpt=uo%3D2)

I also looked at [webview shows blank page](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/), and from that i added the following code to mine (inside the webviewclient class)

```
public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
    handler.proceed() ;
}
```

------ EDIT, my activity extends SherlockFragmentActivity and implements LoaderCallbacks and my code is as under for the first activity

```
private ListView mListView;
private Cursor mCursor;
private MyListAdapter mListAdapter;


private CursorLoader mCursorLoader;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    fillDataIntoCursor();
    new GetDataAsyncTask(this, mLimit).execute();
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void fillDataIntoCursor() {
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
mListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this,mCursor,false);
mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mCursor = mListAdapter.getCursor();
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String link = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyTable.COL_NAME_HERE));
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("link",link);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
 if(mListAdapter!=null && cursor!=null)
    mListAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursor) {
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle bundle) {
String[] projection = { // columns here};
mCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
return mCursorLoader;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

**PS: When i replace the url with [Google](http://www.google.com) the mainactivity does not restart. Also there are no conifg changes that take place which might cause the restart**

I also get this error **10-09 21:02:53.229: E/InputDispatcher(156): channel '40bed3f0 packagename_here/packagename_here.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8**

Comment: So you have activity A from which you start B, and after 2 minutes A got restared, i understand that you know that it is restarted by manually going back?

Comment: Yes correct : Activity A-> Activity B-> Activity A.
No i did not get to know about the restart by going back, i was viewing the webpage and Activity A started, i know it because Activity A populates data, so the entire process repeated again

Comment: Strange, can you post Activity A code?

Comment: Give me a moment i will post the code as an edit. Thanks

Comment: code posted as an edit.

Comment: why are you not finished activity A.. ?

Comment: Its a listview i need to retain it inside of finishing it so. And the webview restarts the application without user intervention

Comment: yeah but why you need that listview.?? you can get that list on back press..

Comment: true but then i think it would be appropriate if i retain the listview, because the listview implements on scroll listener and loads more items, instead of keeping track as to how many items were loaded before moving to the next activity, retaining the first acctivity is better

Comment: ohkkk.. then how did you find that activity A is restarting.?

Comment: Because the data gets reloaded. Thats why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38942/discussion-between-segi-and-dhara-shah)